# Android: cannot convert from String to Editable

Tags: android, string

A quick question:

I am getting the error : cannot convert from String to Editable.
Here is the code :

```
Credential.getInstance().UserName = preferences.getString("UserName", "invalid value");
Credential.getInstance().Password = preferences.getString("UserName", "invalid value");
```

I've also tried casting like following:

```
Credential.getInstance().UserName = (Editable) preferences.getString("UserName", "invalid value");
Credential.getInstance().Password = (Editable) preferences.getString("UserName", "invalid value");
```

This time I am getting error : Cannot cast from String to Editable.

What to do?

Comment: What is `Credential.getInstance()`?

Comment: Singleton class, but its out of the scope of this question.
:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Surely:

```
Credential.getInstance().UserName.append(preferences.getString("UserName", "invalid value"));
```

The API with the answers:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Editable.html

Comment: I am getting this error: The method setText(String) is undefined for the type Editable. I am using eclipse and android 1.6.

Comment: append method gives the NullPointerException.

Comment: Yes this is your next error, but this one is fixed. One of your variables is null, UserName or preferences. Mark answered, look at your LogCat and go fix :-)

Comment: I appreciate your co-operation, I have also used this code, `Credential.getInstance().UserName.append("a static value");` but this fix value also give the NullPointerException. What about this one?

Comment: Credential.getInstance() may be returning null. You should debug this and find out :p

Comment: I have also tried this:
`Credential cre = Credential.getInstance();
  if(cre==null)
  {
   Log.w("is error there?","Is error there?");
  }`


by this I am sure that Credential.getInstance() isn't returning a null value.

Should I instantiate the UserName variable(which is the Editable variable)?
If yes then how?

Comment: Yes if UserName is null then this is your problem. I don't know because I don't know how your credential class works :-)

Comment: No Problem, finally changed the Credential Class and changed the data type of UserName from Editable to String. So my problem has been sorted out in a different way from this question.

I couldn't test the answer myself yet after trusting you I marked the answer corrected just because I don't want someone else to get frustrated for a couple of hour just for tiny thing.

:)

Answer (score 6):

For anyone interested in converting a String to Editable

```
Editable.Factory.getInstance().newEditable("myString");
```

From the docs, append is

*Convenience for append(String.valueOf(text)).*