# How can I create run time entry for email and password in following code?

Tags: java, android, email, gmail

Following is the code of Main.java file.

```
package com.app.mail1;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

 public class Main extends Activity {

EditText to, from, message, subject; 

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {


            try {   
                GMailSender sender = new GMailSender("rockstarjamunjuice@gmail.com", "jamunjuice");
                sender.sendMail("This is Subject",   
                        "This is Body",   
                        "user@gmail.com",   
                        "user@yahoo.com");   
            } catch (Exception e) {   
                Log.e("SendMail", e.getMessage(), e);   
            } 

        }
    });

}
}
```

Here is the code for GMailSender.java file

```
package com.app.mail1;
import javax.activation.DataHandler;   
import javax.activation.DataSource;   
import javax.mail.Message;   
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;   
import javax.mail.Session;   
import javax.mail.Transport;   
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;   
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;   
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;   
import java.io.IOException;   
import java.io.InputStream;   
import java.io.OutputStream;   
import java.security.Security;   
import java.util.Properties;   

public class GMailSender extends javax.mail.Authenticator {   
private String mailhost = "smtp.gmail.com";   
private String user;   
private String password;   
private Session session;   

static {   
    Security.addProvider(new com.provider.JSSEProvider());   
}  

public GMailSender(String user, String password) {   
    this.user = user;   
    this.password = password;   

    Properties props = new Properties();   
    props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");   
    props.setProperty("mail.host", mailhost);   
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");   
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");   
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");   
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",   
            "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");   
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");   
    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.quitwait", "false");   

    session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, this);   
}   

protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {   
    return new PasswordAuthentication(user, password);   
}   

public synchronized void sendMail(String subject, String body, String sender, String recipients) throws Exception {   
    try{
    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);   
    DataHandler handler = new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(body.getBytes(), "text/plain"));   
    message.setSender(new InternetAddress(sender));   
    message.setSubject(subject);   
    message.setDataHandler(handler);   
    if (recipients.indexOf(',') > 0)   
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(recipients));   
    else  
        message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipients));   
    Transport.send(message);   
    }catch(Exception e){

    }
}   

public class ByteArrayDataSource implements DataSource {   
    private byte[] data;   
    private String type;   

    public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data, String type) {   
        super();   
        this.data = data;   
        this.type = type;   
    }   

    public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data) {   
        super();   
        this.data = data;   
    }   

    public void setType(String type) {   
        this.type = type;   
    }   

    public String getContentType() {   
        if (type == null)   
            return "application/octet-stream";   
        else  
            return type;   
    }   

    public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {   
        return new ByteArrayInputStream(data);   
    }   

    public String getName() {   
        return "ByteArrayDataSource";   
    }   

    public OutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {   
        throw new IOException("Not Supported");   
    }   
}   
}
```

Can I set the username and password at run time? 
Can I make String to Editable?
Please help me if I can edit this code and set sender's email id and password at run time?

Comment: make 1 provider like php who send email id and password from server when user click on it

Answer (score 0):

1. [Howto convert String to Editable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5702949/android-cannot-convert-from-string-to-editable)
2. Howto change username/password:

Add this to class:

```
public class Main extends Activity {
    private static String password;
    private static String username;

    public static void setUsername(String user){
        username = user;
    }

    public static void setPassword(String pass){
        password = pass;
    }
    // ...................................
    GMailSender sender = new GMailSender(username, password);

}
```

Then, you can change pass/name:

```
public class SomeClass {
    Main.setUsername("SomeUser");
    Main.setPassword("StrongPassword");
}
```

[Or you can use Intent for transfer data (username/password) in Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android)